# How is time "homogeneous"?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, time, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames

My [book](http://scifunam.fisica.unam.mx/mir/copit/LT0001ES/LT0001ES.html)$^1$ states:

> Let's consider a clock moving freely over a curve such as:
>   \begin{equation}
> \frac{dx^i}{dt}=\text{const} \tag{1.20}
> \end{equation}
>   We define the proper time $\tau$ as the time measured from the clock's perpective. Since time is homogeneous (time is symmetric) then:
>   \begin{equation}
> \frac{dt}{d\tau}=\text{const}. \tag{1.21}
> \end{equation}

My question is, what does it means for the time to be "symmetric"? What does that derivative mean?

$^1$Saúl Ramos-Sánchez (2018). Relatividad para futuros físicos (1st ed. pp. 11). Retrieved from http://scifunam.fisica.unam.mx/mir/copit/LT0001ES/LT0001ES.html

Comment: Are you sure that you are not omitting some important qualifications while truncating the quote from your book? The statement as stated seems wrong. $d\tau=\sqrt{1-v^2}dt$ and thus, $\frac{dt}{d\tau}$ is not constant along the curve unless the $3-$ velocity **v** (in the given coordinate system) is constant along the curve.

Comment: @DvijMankad You are completely right! De velocity is constant, I will add the information that I omitted by writing [...]

Comment: Good question. I believe time is homogeneous if the clock is ticking at a constant rate in the rest frame of the clock. In other words, if there is a  mapping $F:t \rightarrow t$ between any two points $p$ and $q$ on $t$ such that $F(p)=q$ then time is homogeneous. All coordinates in semi-Riemannian space are assumed to homogeneous, i.e., they preserve the metric.

Comment: @CinaedSimson being homogeneous means to preserve the metric? So that means that coordinate time, no matter who measures it, will preserve the invariance of the spacetime interval. Am I right? I am still confused about the relation between the last derivative and the homogeneous property.

Comment: @DvijMankad does that means that for accelerated inertial frames time is not symmetric?

Comment: @IchVerloren: no, the clock tick is in the rest frame of the clock. Different frames will measure different time intervals. And no, it's the time interval not the spacetime interval. My comment was about the time interval only. See Dvij Mankad comment - the equation you gave is incorrect.